# Select first joined value, not all

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tables:

```
'gallery' - information about existing galleries 
id_gallery  name     date
==========  ====  ===========
    1        ...   timestamp

'photo' - information and name of every photo in system
id_photo   photo_name
========   ===========
   1        some name 

'photo_gallery' - "connecting" table, which says which photo are in which gallery
id_photo_gallery   id_photo           id_gallery
================   ================   =================
       1           id from 'photo'    id from 'gallery'
```

I need to select gallery (with some inforamtion about it, but, that's not important) and only ONE id of photo from 'photo' table.

This (for a big surprise) return all photos. (Duplicated informations about gallery)

```
SELECT 
    photo_gallery.id_photo as id_photo
FROM
    gallery
        JOIN
    photo_gallery ON gallery.id_gallery = photo_gallery.id_gallery
```

**EDIT**

This return only one gallery, not many. I need to retrieve one photo per one gallery ...

```
SELECT 
    photo_gallery.id_photo as id_photo
FROM
    gallery
        JOIN
    photo_gallery ON gallery.id_gallery = photo_gallery.id_gallery LIMIT 1
```

Comment: So you want specific record based on id

Comment: you can use the aggregation function you want (MIN, MAX) : `select min(photo_gallery.id_photo) as id_photo <FROM... JOIN> GROUP BY <not aggregated fields>`

Comment: Can you please write complete SQL? I don't know how ...

Comment: (Duplicated informations about gallery) then use `LIMIT`.

Comment: When I use LIMIT, I get only one gallery

Comment: On what Database are you on?

Comment: Did you check my (@user2727841) updated answer...

Comment: If you want latest last 10 records use limit after `ORDER BY gallery.id_gallery DESC LIMIT 10`.

Comment: @user2727841: But there will be duplicated values ;)

Comment: thats why because didn't use `where` clause in query then create a group of gallery ids...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following query:

```
SELECT galery.*, photo.* 
FROM galery
LEFT JOIN photo_gallery ON galery.id = photo_gallery.id_gallery
LEFT JOIN photo ON photo_gallery.id_photo = photo.id
GROUP BY galery.id
```

Comment: Why not? `GROUP BY galery.id` will help produce one record per gallery.

Comment: That's not correct because you have photo.* in my opinion

Comment: Perfect! It works perfectly as I desire! :) Thank you so much! :)

Comment: @Tobi You are right if the query does not have `GROUP BY galery.id`

Comment: @RainbowBronyCZ I'm glad that I could help!

Comment: @Tobi That is the smallest thing in my problem.

Answer (score 0):

use LIMIT

```
SELECT 
    pg.id_photo
FROM gallery g
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT id_gallery, MAX(id_photo) AS id_photo photo_gallery pg
    GROUP BY id_gallery
) AS pg
    ON g.id_gallery = pg.id_gallery
```

Comment: this will retrieve only one gallery, not only one photo per gallery, which seems to be the desired result (but I may be wrong)

Comment: why a subquery in the new version ? It maybe needed in some cases, but seems overkill in this one.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT
gallery.name,
photo.photo_name
FROM
  gallery
  INNER JOIN photo_gallery
    ON (gallery.id_gallery = photo_gallery.id_gallery)
  INNER JOIN photo
    ON (photo.id_photo = photo_gallery.id_photo_gallery)
ORDER BY gallery.id_gallery DESC
```

if you want to more data write fields name...

Comment: I need to select last ten galleries with informations and one photo .. LIMIT doesn't help ...